# Why am I not able to export a variable from one file to another

Tags: node.js

when I try to print a variable using module.exports ,it is not working

I have created two files index.js and function.js. In function.js I have declared one variable foo and I am trying to export it . In index .js I am just trying to print the variable foo

function.js
 `var foo=45;`
`module.exports = foo;`

index.js
 `var func=require('./function.js');`
 `console.log(func);`

it should return 45 but it is returning a null object

Comment: Please show your actual code.

Comment: Actually its working... Maybe there is some other issue .. but the code that you provided is actually working.. having both file in same folder and running the index.js from same directory resulting in 45 not `null` object....

Comment: is there some setting problem ? I have already installed npm. Should I install something else ?

Answer (score 0):

Do some modification in function.js as

```
let foo=45; 
module.exports = { foo };
```

In index.js as

```
let func=require('./function.js'); 
console.log(func.foo); // Now you can see 45
```